# Show only taxonomy types associated with a custom post type in WordPress PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to display only the taxonomy types selected on a custom post type "newsroom". The code below shows all taxonomy types for every type of post. Is there a way to show only the types tagged on a post under the custom post type "newsroom"?

```
        <form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="resource_filter">
        <?php
            if( $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'types', 'orderby' => 'name' ) ) ) { // types
                ?> <div class="types-filter"><h3>Types</h3> <?php
              foreach ( $terms as $term ){ ?>
                <label class="MuiFormControlLabel-root">
                    <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root jss317 MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorSecondary MuiIconButton-colorSecondary" aria-disabled="false">
                        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="types_filter[]" id="checkbox_types_filter_<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" class="resource-filter-checkbox" value="<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" data-indeterminate="false" data_term_name="<?php echo $term->name; ?>">
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="MuiTypography-root MuiFormControlLabel-label MuiTypography-body1">
                        <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2"><?php echo $term->name; ?></p>
                    </span>
                </label>
              <?php 
                }
              ?> 
              </div> 
        <?php
            } ?>
     </form>
```

Comment: This question was answered on [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/421343). Please read this note on cross-posting: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068#64069).